# IOS - Could not cast value of type NSKnownKeysDictionary1

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I need to `distinct` one `field` like bellow:

```
func fetchListLanguagesContentDegreesPage(catId: Int64,
                                          locale: String,
                                          completionHandler: @escaping (() throws -> [Degrees]) -> Void) {
    privateManagedObjectContext.perform {
        do {
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Degrees")
            let query = NSPredicate(format: "(%K = %@) AND (%K = %@)",
                                    "locale",locale,
                                    "parentID",String(catId))
            fetchRequest.predicate = query
            fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.dictionaryResultType
            fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["langName"]
            fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
            let results = try self.privateManagedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Degrees]
            completionHandler{return results}
        } catch {
            completionHandler { throw DegreesStoreError.CannotFetch("Cannot fetch orders") }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the project get me crash and say:

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSKnownKeysDictionary1' to 'PortalAlmostafaApp.Degrees'
```

What can I do? How can I cast `NSKnownKeysDictionary1` ?